# How do I set password for Hotspot?

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, network-manager, password, hot-spot

I have an active wired LAN connection and want to share it via my wireless radio, requiring a password to connect.  This should be super easy, right?

I am running Kubuntu 20.04.

When I go into the Network Manager I see the hotspot button.  I press it and immediately a hotspot connection is available for other users, but it is unsecure - no password required.  Most documentation I have read on this topic says that some kind of dialogue should occur at this point, but that is not happening in this case.  I hit the Hotspot button and the connection becomes available without any hesitation, or any security.

[image: Hotspot activated]

Then I use the Network Manager's "Connections" interface to edit the hotspot properties, enabling WPA security and setting a password.  I hit Apply, OK.  Yet, the connection remains unsecure.

[image: Connections window]

Am I missing something here?   Please advise.

I have gone through this process several times and see no viable alternatives.

The Network Manager shows this connection in the exact same format as any other wifi connection.  That doesn't seem right to me.  It's as if the password I am entering is for logging-in to this connection.  Of course, I don't want to log-in. I want other devices to log in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the HOTSPOT button doesn't work properly here in Kubuntu 20.04.  I'm not sure why.

The solution for me was to manually create an Access Point (aka hotspot) connection using either nm-connection-editor or the built in Connections interface.  This webpage helped me out:
https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/2-ways-to-create-wifi-hotspot-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts-focal-fossa.html

It's pretty easy.

1. Make a new wifi connection
2. Set the mode to AccessPoint/Hotspot
3. Choose WPA security and set your password.
4. Save your new connection.

Now it will show up in your list of available connections so that you can connect or disconnect at your convenience.

Using the built-in Hotspot button creates a new connection every time you press the button, which creates a mess of duplicates in your list of connections.  That plus the lack of security are two reasons I do not recommend using the HOTSPOT button in Kubuntu 20.04.